# Can you use fonts you've downloaded on your computer in a local project?

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

Disclaimer: I'm a noob so please don't use too many hard terms when answering lol

I have a couple of cute fonts I downloaded from dafont and am hoping to use in my coding project from school. I'm calling it a local project because it will not be uploaded online, we'll just be sending the markers a zip file of the work we've done. I was wondering if the markers will actually be able to view the fonts that I'm wanting to use?

Would I be safer using google fonts? But I tried downloading one and it wouldn't show up when I wrote it like:

```
p {
font-family: Nunito;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and it didn't do the typical autocomplete, and saving it and running it didn't make it work.

Here's the entire code:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

h1 {
    color: #b98b82;
    font-family: Seritta, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif
}

p {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you tried to use that google font - not just the font-family selection.

Comment: @AHaworth Hi, that's all I did. It is downloaded to my computer, I don't really know how google font APIs work.

I've edited the post and added my full CSS file, it's in the beginning stages so don't worry about how little there is in it.

Comment: You can find out how to use google fonts here https://fonts.google.com/

Comment: If in your html page you are using fonts not installed on a given machine, you need to specify the used `font-family` with a [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts) ruleset that will link that font-family with font types available at the linked assets (being woff, ttf, base64...). Usually when you download a web font you have the instructions on what to include in your page but you can just visit the link I shared before pointing at mdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded your fonts, you can just add your font files to your project. I recommend adding them to a folder (maybe call it "fonts").
After you added them, just add a @font-face to your css.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'YourFont';
src:  url('fonts/yourfont.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

To use it now, you just have to specify the font-family, for example:

```
body{
font-family: 'YourFont';
}
```